# Why does jQuery get img width not work on first try?

Tags: jquery, image, width

Not sure if I can explain this adequately, but here it goes. I am doing a hover over a spot and display a picture with a frame/background and a caption. This all actually works really great except the very first time I hover...

I am trying to retrieve the width of an image with the following code:

```
/* Retrieve the width of the image */
var trashImg = new Image(); // declare an image object
trashImg.src = this.href;   // instanciate it to the current image
IMG_WIDTH = trashImg.width; // get the width of the image
```

The problem is, the first time I hover, it retrieves the "trashImg.src" properly but "trashImg.width" returns 0 (zero). The second time I hover, "trashImg.width" returns the correct size. I do have this code inside "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {..." function so presumably the image is loaded at this point.

I have been staring at this code for hours and can't figure out why. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way that I have written my code, the only way that I was able to make this work, was to preload the images.

```
$('div.imgTooltip').children().each(function(){
    /* Preload the images */
    var trashImg = new Image(); // declare an image object
    trashImg.src = this.href;   // instantiate it to the current image
    $('.profile').append(trashImg); // insert preloaded image into the DOM tree
});
```

Now by the time this code

```
/* Retrieve the width of the image */
var trashImg = new Image(); // declare an image object
trashImg.src = this.href;   // instanciate it to the current image
IMG_WIDTH = trashImg.width; // get the width of the image
```

executes, the images are already loaded. I don't know if this is truly the best way to do this but it seems to work (at least it did throughout my extensive testing).

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting until the image actually gets loaded.

You should wrap the `width` check into the image's `load` event handler:

```
trashImg.onload = function() { IMG_WIDTH = trashImg.width; } 
trashImg.src = this.href;  // Remember to do this AFTER defining the load handler
```

*(it may be possible to refer to the image as `this`  instead of `trashImg`inside the load function but I'm not sure right now whether that will fully work as expected)*

Note that you don't know when the `load` event will be fired, so you need to put all code that depends on `IMG_WIDTH` into that function (or call it from there).

While this will usually work, the load event on images has some known unreliabilities that  is good to know about. From the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I did not realize that the image might not yet be loaded... In my case the simple solution would be to add the width as an attribute to the HTML element and retrieve it's value instead.?! I will give that a try right now.

Comment: OK, my above thought did not work due to the way that I'm doing things. BUT I found a way to make this work thanks to your insight. I am pre-loading all the images, so by the time it reaches the code in question, the image is already loaded. Been testing the crap out of it and it seems to be working flawlessly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

document.ready doesn't mean all images are loaded already, just that the "basic structure" is loaded(so you know you can find all ids etc.). You can check out the load() function: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ to do this properly

Comment: What you say is generally correct, but it doesn't apply to the situation at hand: The OP is *creating* a new image element, potentially after both `ready` and `load` have already fired.